# Using @list_route and @detail_route together

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a special operation on a model A, which adds objects (instances of model B) to a m2m relationship.  I want to be able to both add instances of model B in the same request that I am creating an instance of model A.  To do this I would use `@list_route(methods=['post'])`.

But I also want to be able to add instances of model B to an instance of model A which has already been created.  For this I would use `@detail_route(methods=['patch'])`.  However, the only difference in how these to views operate is in fetching/creating the instance of model A.  Ideally I would make this a single function that tests `request.method` when fetching an instance of model A.  That would look something like this:

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
@detail_route(methods=['patch'])
def my_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create and fetch instance of model A
        instance = A.objects.create(some_paramaters_here)
    else if request.method == 'PATCH':
        instance = self.get_object()

    # do things to add to instance
    for thing in request:
        instance.add(thing)

    return 201 # and fetch json output from serializer that I omitted here
```

But I'm really concerned about using both decorators here.  Will it work?  Are best practices in this scenario any different?